# Is there a right way to layout my CSS?

Tags: css

this is my first post so excuse me if I'm doing anything wrong. My question is how should I layout my CSS files? Just curious to see if there's a "right way" CSS should be written. Thanks!

Comment: https://smacss.com/ and https://en.bem.info/ are two popular methodologies.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

CSS should be laid out by specificity.

IDs are more specific than classes which are more specific than tags. Therefore you would want general tag styles at the top of your sheet and then classes and the IDs.

`p { }`

`.p { }`

`#p { }`

You can also, matter of preference, in large projects, separate CSS styles into different sheets to make it easier for other people to read through your code.

CSS is whitespace insensitive so it tabbing will not make the compilation change, but it is of course common practice to tab accordingly.

There are plenty of other rules that many programmers follow, but the majority of them are opinionated so it is up to you to adopt an efficient way to layout your CSS. Even the rules I have stated will not "break" your  CSS if not used, but they tend to help cause less problems. Research this topic further and try and adopt a set of rules to follow and stay consistent with them.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding how browsers parse CSS and render websites is an important first step towards writing more efficient code.

There are four kinds of **key selectors**: **ID, class, tag, and universal**. It is that same order in how efficient they are.

```
#main-navigation {   }      /* ID (Fastest) */
body.home #page-wrap {   }  /* ID */
.main-navigation {   }      /* Class */
ul li a.current {   }       /* Class *
ul {   }                    /* Tag */
ul li a {  }                /* Tag */
* {   }                     /* Universal (Slowest) */
#content [title='home']     /* Universal */
```

You can refer below articles to write more efficient CSS

[**Efficiently rendering css**](https://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/)

[**Writing efficient css selectors**](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/)

Answer (score -1):

You can indent your css. Or minimize it at the end of the project.
You can use plenty of websites that can help you to do it.

[That's an example - CleanCSS](http://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/)